# R - Automatize Multiplot Input ggPlot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, automation

I have a list of `ggplot`s called `plotlist1`. I want to create a multiplot of those plots, who are linked together.

For creating a multiplot I use:

```
grid.arrange(plotlist[[1]], plotlist1[[1]], plotlist1[[2]])
```

`plotlist[[1]]` has to be added as the first plot.

The problem is that I have to do a lot of these multiplot and I want to automatize it. To identify those plots that are related, I created a list of the names of these plots, called `namelist`.

Plots starting with the same letter are related, so I did this:

```
position = which(grepl("A", namelist))
n = length(position)
```

It gives me the position of the plots in the `plotlist1`, that I want to plot together. My problem is now, how can I create the grid.arrange command automatically? I tried to recreate it with past and replicate, but I am just not getting anywhere.

This is my try:

```
base1 = paste(replicate(lang, "plotlist1"))
base2 = paste(replicate(n, "[["))
base3 = paste(replicate(n, "]]"))
base4 = paste0(base2, position)
base5 = paste0(base4, base3)
base6 = paste0(base1, base5, collapse = ",")
base7 = paste0("plotlist[[1]],", base6)

grid_arrange(base7)
grid_arrange(as.factor(base7))
```

The namelist:

```
c("A00-A09", "A09", "B85-B89", "B99", "C-D4", "F10", "F10-F19", 
"G40", "G40-G47", "G45", "H0-H5", "H00-H06", "H10", "H10-H13", 
"H15-H22", "H16", "H6-H9", "H65", "H65-H75", "I10", "I10-I15", 
"I20", "I20-I25", "I30-I52", "I4-I74", "I50", "I60-I69", "I63", 
"I70-I79", "I80", "I80-I82", "I80-I89", "J00-J06", "J06", "J18", 
"J20", "J20-J22", "J22", "J40", "J40-J47", "J44", "J9-J18", "K35", 
"K35-K38", "K55-K64", "K56", "K80-K87", "L00-L08", "M00-M25", 
"M40-M54", "M54", "M60-M79", "N10-N16", "N20-N23", "N23", "N30-N39", 
"N39", "N40-N51", "O20-O29", "R00-R09", "R06", "R07", "R07-4", 
"R10", "R10-R19", "R20-R23", "R30-R39", "R40-R46", "R50-R69", 
"R51", "R55", "S00", "S00-S09", "S01", "S06", "S20", "S20-S29", 
"S30-S39", "S40-S49", "S42", "S50-S59", "S52", "S60", "S60-S69", 
"S61", "S70-S79", "S80-S89", "S82", "S90", "S90-S99", "S91", 
"S93", "T08-T14", "T15", "T15-T19", "T63", "T66-T78", "T78", 
"T80-T88", "T83")
```

Comment: Use `do.call(grid.arrange, plotlist)`

Comment: But how does the plotlist should look like? That is where I am stucking.

Comment: I assume your `plotlist` as a `list of plots?

Comment: Yes, but I have a plotlist, containing "overview"-plots and then I have a plotlist1 with detailed plots. I want to match now the overview-plot with the detailed plots in plotlist1. For example Plot "A" in the Plotlist has to be on one plot with all other plots starting with an "A" out of plotlist1.

Comment: Did you meant `split(namelist, substr(namelist, 1, 1))` to split into a block of plot names

Comment: No. But, actually, the stuff you deleted now, was nearly the solution. do.call(grid.arrange, plotlist1[grep("A", namelist)]) nearly did it, I only need to add the overview plot first, in that case it is plotlist[[1]]. The numbers are like A = 1, B = 2, C=3, F = 4, ...,

Comment: Does ` do.call(grid.arrange, c(plotlist1[1], plotlist1[grep("A", namelist)]))` works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may either use `do.call` with `grid.arrange`

```
 do.call(grid.arrange, c(plotlist1[1], plotlist1[grep("A", namelist)]))
```

or with

```
library(ggpubr)
n1 <- 3
n2 <- 4
ggarrange(plotlist = plotlist, ncol = n1, nrow = n2)
```

Comment: I think you understood me wrong. My problem is how to create the plotlist1. It has to be a subset ot the whole plotlist1. And that subset is always different in length depending on the first letter of their names.

Comment: @Mr.Spock Suppose you are subsetting the `plotlist` based on the pattern in namelist, which should be the names of plotlist? then `do.call(grid.arrange, plotlist[grep("A", namelist)])`

Comment: Thank so you much! The do.call function was what I searched for! It works exactly how I wanted!